# Unable to remove deployed printers from workstations via GPO

Tags: group-policy, domain, printing, network-printer, workstation-management

I have about 40 printers which are were deployed in old method (GPO - user - deployed printers)
Each printer have a security group in Permissions tab users whom can use it.
For now i have a problem that some printers appeares at workstations where user doesn't have a permissions if he not in security group of that printer.

For example:
user1 added to security group printer01-print-group and he able to print to printer01. But he also see printers which he used earlier and then was deleted from group: printer02, printer03, etc. They are not accessible to him but he can see the on the list.

In GPP i tried the user policy "Printer" and set it to delete all printers from workstations. But some printer deleted and some printers didn't.

In GP result i had an error:

`0x80070005 access is denied`

What i tried to do:
1.add `SYSTEM` account to printer security on print server 
2.add `DOMAIN COMPUTERS` to printer security on print server
3.Trying to delete `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Connections`

What i'm doing wrong? How can i deleted inactive printers wich are not accessible?

thank you!

Comment: I noticed that if i create the same GPO in another OU and move user to that OU GPO is working...